# Why is my 3 table JOIN MySQL query not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
Table: album
Columns: id, name, description, author, path, image

Table: albumconnect
Columns: id, imageid, albumid

Table: albumimages
Columns: id, path
```

And I'm trying to replace all those unnecessary queries with a single JOIN query:

```
<?php

        $albumID = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $realAlbumID = substr($albumID, 1);
        $realestAlbumID = str_replace('%20', ' ', $realAlbumID);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM album WHERE id='$realestAlbumID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $albumPath = $getResult['path'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM albumconnect WHERE albumid='$realestAlbumID'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

        while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            $imageId = $row['imageid']; 
            $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM albumimages WHERE id='$imageId'";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
            $getResult3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
            $imagePath = $getResult3['path'];
            echo '<div class="imageContainerAlbums"><li class="listAlbums"><img class="specificAlbumThumnails" src="'.$albumPath.$imagePath.'" alt="Random image" /></li></div>';
        };

?>
```

Now the JOIN query I've come up with based on stuff I've read online is this:

```
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM album
                JOIN albumconnect ON albumconnect.albumid=album.id
                JOIN albumimages ON albumimages.id=albumconnect.imageid
                WHERE id='$realestAlbumID'";
        $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
```

However, when I try to var_dump the contents, it prints Null so I assume my query is incorrect but I can't figure out the correct way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried the query directly with made up variables in PHPmyAdmin or something else?

Comment: Yes, I already have values in my database.

Comment: I mean, run the query directly with a SQL command and see if your joins work.

Comment: Oh, It say 'Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous'

Comment: It doesn't know which id column from which table you need.

Comment: Question: Since your table is named `albumimages`, why do you use a buffer table like `albumconnect`? It would make sense only if you have had many images for one album AND one image on many albums. Otherwise you don't need `albumconnect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this. I didn't test it. As @Difster correctly said, SQL engine doesn't know which `id` should it reference. So, define table aliases and prefix the referenced columns with them. Then define unique aliases for the column names too. Otherwise your sql statement were almost perfect.

```
<?php

$albumID = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$realAlbumID = substr($albumID, 1);
$realestAlbumID = str_replace('%20', ' ', $realAlbumID);

$sql = "SELECT 
            alb.name AS album_name,
            alb.description AS album_description,
            alb.author AS album_author,
            alb.path AS album_path,
            alb.image AS album_image,
            ali.path AS image_path
        FROM album AS alb
        LEFT JOIN albumconnect AS alc ON alc.albumid = alb.id
        LEFT JOIN albumimages AS ali ON ali.id = alc.imageid
        WHERE alb.id = '$realestAlbumID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $albumPath = $row['album_path'];
    $imagePath = $row['image_path'];
    echo '<div class="imageContainerAlbums">';
    echo '<li class="listAlbums">';
    echo '<img class="specificAlbumThumnails" src="' . $albumPath . $imagePath . '" alt="Random image" />';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

The columns from the sql statement which you don't use later are optional. So, you don't need to select all columns if you don't need them later.

It maybe that you are also becoming rows with NULL values for `alc` or `ali` tables. It means that not all albums have images. Then you must give us values you have in the tables, so that we can provide you the proper further WHERE conditions like `WHERE ali IS NOT NULL`. This answer of me is just the starting point for you.

**EDIT 2:**

This version is ok too. I just changed the sql statement.

```
<?php

$albumID = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$realAlbumID = substr($albumID, 1);
$realestAlbumID = str_replace('%20', ' ', $realAlbumID);

$sql = "SELECT 
            alb.name AS album_name,
            alb.description AS album_description,
            alb.author AS album_author,
            alb.path AS album_path,
            alb.image AS album_image,
            ali.path AS image_path
        FROM albumimages AS ali 
        LEFT JOIN albumconnect AS alc ON alc.imageid = ali.id 
        LEFT JOIN album AS alb ON alb.id = alc.albumid 
        WHERE alb.id = '$realestAlbumID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $albumPath = $row['album_path'];
    $imagePath = $row['image_path'];
    echo '<div class="imageContainerAlbums">';
    echo '<li class="listAlbums">';
    echo '<img class="specificAlbumThumnails" src="' . $albumPath . $imagePath . '" alt="Random image" />';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I was able to more or less grasp how to use JOIN thanks to those examples. Also your question about the intermediary table made me realize I actually don't need it at all. Thank you for that.

Comment: @PeterAtanasov You are very welcome. I wrote (and deleted) that you can even remove table `albumimages` also, and move image `path` to `album`. So you can remain with one table: `album`. But I would be maybe wrong in the case when you would indeed want to have an images collection separately, from which you could pick the images as you'd wish. Or maybe not, and it then would make sense to save the image `path` as album detail in `album` table. So is actually your decision, based on your vision and use-case. Good luck!